# What do the numbers mean when you are training a NVlabs/stylegan2

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, stylegan

What do these numbers mean when you are training a style-gan

```
tick 60    kimg 242.0    time 1h 55m 54s   sec/tick 104.7   sec/kimg 25.96   maintenance 0.0    gpumem 7.3   augment 0.105
```

The one that I'm worried about is Augment cause it appears to be going flipping between 0.105 and 0.104 every tick and I can't tell if that bad or okay.

**One I think I know**

Tick: Is the number of times information has been displayed.

Time: Is how long it's been training

Sec/Tick: Is second between each Tick:

**Ones I have no idea about**

kimg ????

sec/kimg ????

augment ????

**Best Guess**

gpumem: Number of GPU's used?

maintenance: During certain ticks it create a restore point on, the time it take to make the restore point is located here?

Answer (score 3):

"nimg" or "kimg", which stand for number of images or thousands of images. So 1kimg = 1000nimg = 1000 images.